# How to suppress table in `aggr` function of `Vim`

Tags: r

I am doing some descriptive analysis, and all what I want is the graphic from `VIM::aggr`. However, when I set `sortVars = T` or `sortCombs = T`, the plot command also shows a table:

```
ds <- structure(list(RC_1 = c(4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 
7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5), RC_2 = c(NA, 7, 7, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5), RC_3 = c(7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), RC_4 = c(7, 7, 5, 7, 
6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
mice_plot <- aggr(ds, plot = F)
plot(mice_plot,
     col = c('navyblue','yellow'),
          ylab = c("Proporção de Dados Faltantes","Padrão de dados Faltantes"),
     numbers = T,
     sortVars = T,
     sortCombs = T,
     gap = 2)
```

Output in Rmarkdown:
[image]

How can I omit the below table? (via R code or RMarkdown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to capture the output and direct to a temporary file

```
capture.output(plot(mice_plot,
     col = c('navyblue','yellow'),
           ylab = c("Proporção de Dados Faltantes","Padrão de dados Faltantes"),
      numbers = T,
      sortVars = T,
      sortCombs = T,
      gap = 2), file = tempfile())
```

-checking in markdown

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r first}
suppressMessages(library(VIM))
ds <- structure(list(RC_1 = c(4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 
7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5), RC_2 = c(NA, 7, 7, 6, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5), RC_3 = c(7, 4, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), RC_4 = c(7, 7, 5, 7, 
6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
mice_plot <- aggr(ds, plot = F)

```

```{r second, echo=FALSE}
capture.output(plot(mice_plot,
     col = c('navyblue','yellow'),
          ylab = c("Proporção de Dados Faltantes","Padrão de dados Faltantes"),
     numbers = T,
     sortVars = T,
     sortCombs = T,
     gap = 2), file = tempfile())
```
````

-output

[image]

---

The output is from the `plot.aggr` `cat` prints

```
getAnywhere('plot.aggr')
...
...
 if (sortVars) {
        if (!imputed) 
            cat("\n Variables sorted by number of missings: \n")
        else if (!miss_imp) 
            cat("\n Variables sorted by number of imputed missings: \n")
        else cat("\n Variables sorted by number of missings or imputed missings: \n")
        tmp <- data.frame(Variable = cn, Count = miss)
        print(tmp, row.names = FALSE)
    }
    invisible()
}
```